# Linear function on a uniform distribution

Tags: statistics

Say $Y$~$U(0,1)$. Now define $W$ as $a+(b-a)Y$. How do I define the distribution function of $W$? I tried using the fact that the pdf of $Y$ is $1/b-a$ for all $y$ $\in$ $S_Y$, but that didn't help me much. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I understood how to resolve it.
Find the cdf $P(a+(b-a)Y\leq w)$ and then it just simply translates to $P(Y\leq w-a/b-a$, which tells us that the cdf $G(W) = w-a/b-a$.